# Подскажите плагин загрузки изображений как в твиттере

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fileupload

Подскажите пожалуйста плагин для загрузки изображений, как в твиттере. Т.е. с возможностью масштабирования и перетаскивания видимой области.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]